# How can I create "cycled" view in Unity 5?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have square UI GameObject which has children, I want to make that when I drag children or child over the edge it would be partically appeared from opposite side (horizontal and/or vertical), so it's kind of splitting one object or maybe rendering same object 2 times (4 times on corners). I can just duplicate objects, but is there a better way?
[image]

Comment: maybe a picture would help? I think you can achieve what I think you mean with four extra camera place on each side of the square.

Comment: eg, say you have cam1 pointing directly at the square, cam2 is to the right of the square by half the square's width. when you drag the child to the edge, cam2 can see the right side of the child which is in its view. both cameras are drawn in the view, so you get half the child on the left and half on the right

Comment: cool pic. yes I think my multiple camera method will work. when the child object moves far enough (ie all the way to the other side, flip its position (back to the same pos as seen by the first camera)

Comment: actually thinking about it you'll need 8 cameras to cope with the corners